# How to get the count of Column values of all the tables present in the database?

Tags: mysql

Can anyone guide or advice me to get the count of Column values of all the tables present in the database excluding 'null' in the total count. I have tried it by using the information schema but couldn't get the expected result. Even the table has 'no entry', it is given some count of 879 or 96?

Here is my query,

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME, COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) -- ,(CASE WHEN COUNT(COLUMN_NAME)=0 THEN '0' ELSE COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) END)
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE 
table_schema= 'TESTING'
GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your query counts the number of times a column name occurs in the information_schema.COLUMNS view. It does not count values within the columns. You can only obtain those counts from the tables. Information schema can be used to dynamically generate the queries for you.

Comment: Then do u have any idea how to get for all the table of my database at a time by grouping into table and column. I have around 472 tables in my database.